# Updated output is concatenating with old output

Tags: java

Can anyone figure out why after removing a found value, the output includes all the information from before the remove?

```
  // Prints current items in both arrays
  String titles = "";
  String lengths = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfSongs; i++) {
     titles += songTitles[i] + " ";
     lengths += songLengths[i] + " ";
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "**Current Playlist**" + "\nSong titles: " + titles + "\nSong lengths: " + lengths);
  // Determines if the user wants to remove a song from the current list 
        boolean found = false;
        // If search matches a song in array, set title to null and length to 0
        for (int i = 0; i < songTitles.length; i++) {
           if (search.equalsIgnoreCase(songTitles[i])) {
              found = true;
              songTitles[i] = null;
              songLengths[i] = 0;
           }
        }
        // Update arrays, song count, and duration across all songs
        if (found) { 
           titles += songTitles[numOfSongs] + " ";
           lengths += songLengths[numOfSongs] + " ";
           totalDuration -= songLengths[numOfSongs];
           numOfSongs--;     
        }
        // Print updated playlist
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "**Current Playlist**" + "\nSong titles: " + titles + "\nSong lengths: " + lengths);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question - It would seem that your problem is caused by using "+=" to concatenate your titles and lengths at the start of your code.  Then you do the "found check" where you continue to add data to the same variable without ever resetting the variables by doing something like titles="" and lengths=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`titles` and `totalDuration` strings are initialized with all the elements in `songTitles` and `songLengths`.

If you find `search` in `songTitles` you remove it from `songTitles` but you don't update `songTitles`. Instead you append on more song title from songTitles.

You probably want to clear `songTitles` and `songLengths` and recreate them skipping null values in `songTitles`. E.g.

```
titles = "";
lengths = "";
for (int i = 0; i < numOfSongs; i++) {
    if (songTitles[i] != null) {
        titles += songTitles[i] + " ";
        lengths += songLengths[i] + " ";
    }
}
```

Also consider creating your strings like this (Java 8)

```
String titles = String.join(" ", songTitles);
String lengths = String.join(" ", songLengths);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below statements are causing to concatenate with old values.

```
titles += songTitles[numOfSongs] + " ";
lengths += songLengths[numOfSongs] + " ";
```

You should first clear the existing values by setting strings empty before adding a new value.

```
titles = "";
lengths = "";
```